# Flutter - UI in simulator and real device are different

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Application UI on my real phone doesn't look like what i expect on simulator.

I was on a small flutter project, normally i develop on Pixel 4 simulator and expect same UI result when i run on my real device. But today, i tried to debug on my phone and see the different, like a lot of things i import to this screen haven't been rendered. I have no clue what happened. Thanks for your answers/reply, hope i can get some keywords or ideas about this issue!
[image: Screen shot on my simulator]
[image: Screen shot on my Samsung phone]

Comment: could you include your code?

Comment: @eamirho3ein it kinda a large code base, [here is my repo] 
 (https://github.com/doanba13/apecint), but all ui page have issues. My screenshot was took from home screen /lib/ui/home/home_page.dart. Hope you find any idea from it. Can you create an issue in my repo? i really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may be loading those images from your disk. Not a 100 percent sure without looking at your code but here are three suggestions:

1. Load the required resources in a folder (STOCK IMAGES) and write code to show messages if they are unable to load ON SCREEN.
2. Often the URL's work on sim but not on the device: try using the following:

   import 'package:vehicle_panel/models/transport.dart';

instead of this:

```
import '/models/transport.dart';
```

Although its loads fine on sim but sometimes gives an issue on the actual device.
3. Open the AndroidManifest.xml file located at ./android/app/src/main and add the following line:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="...">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> <!-- Add this -->
</manifest>
```

sometimes your app does not have access to the internet.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you, i will try it, actually i'm using package import

Answer (score 0):

try this commands

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

then run project again.

Comment: i tried and it's not working

Comment: the problem can also be the wrong widget hierarchy.